# How can I prove calls or messages from a spoofed number are fake?

Tags: spoofing

**Situation**

There are 3 people. Person A, B and the victim, C. Person A asks person B to spoof their phone number to look like the phone number of person C. Person A wants to report person C for harassment using this technique.

**Question**

I know that phone records would show that person C did not make any calls or texts out to person A, but what all besides provide his own phone records could person C do to prove that he was not the one who make the calls or sent the messages?

Comment: Have you contacted your phone provider and changed your number?

Comment: You could contact their cell phone service providers and have them look up the history on their phones.

Comment: If it's not a big deal to you, I love Mr. Mennell's advice of changing your number.  Imagine their disgrace if they reported that you were harassing them from a number you no longer even owned.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, it's important to note that this answer is relevant to United States law, and shouldn't necessarily be taken as legal guidance, more-so a path of reasoning out a solution that may be applicable to you depending on your country etc.

If they choose to actually report the fake evidence to the authorities, you should look into having the police check their call history with their phone service provider, as well as yours. I'm aware of online phone services on the web and through apps that could potentially be used for this kind of thing. Make sure to let the appropriate people know that this is a possibility, in which case they may need to check the suspect's internet history on their computers and ISP.

Faking evidence is unlawful and if you would like, you might could press charges and potentially solve your problem.

Some helpful links below -

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_evidence

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perjury

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malicious_prosecution

Comment: I don't think the OP has said what country they're in so the legal advice may be irrelevant to them

Comment: @NeilSmithline Thanks! I'll keep that in mind next time. Although I believe these laws are relevant in some form in most countries.